# can't create userS via powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016

I can't import users in powershell with a script via an csv file, but If I print the parameters on the screen,it shows them as it should. 
what I am doing wrong? in my life plenty with that mustache, but plis focus on the script.

is running windows server 2016 on the powershell ise, on virtualbox

The Script:

```
If(-Not(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -eq "991-5D"}))
{New-ADOrganizationalUnit "991-5D" -Path (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName}
If(-Not(Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -eq "911-5V"}))
{New-ADOrganizationalUnit "911-5V" -Path (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName}
$domain=(Get-ADDomain).DNSRoot

Import-Csv -Path "C:\Alumnos.csv" | foreach-object {
[int]$number= $_.X
If($number -ge 10 -and $number -le 26)
{
$UO="991-5D"
}
//there  are many others O.U.

$ou= "UO="+$UO+","+$domain
$UPN = $_.LETRA+$_.PATERNO+$_.X+"@"+ "$domain"
$CUENTA= $_.LETRA+$_.PATERNO+$_.X

New-ADUser -SamAccountName $CUENTA -UserPrincipalName $CUENTA -Name $_.NOMBRE 
-SurName $_.PATERNO -GivenName $_.NOMBRE -EmailAddress $UPN -AccountPassword 
(ConvertTo-SecureString "Leica666" -AsPlainText -force) -Path $ou 
-Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Verbose}
```

the data:

```
X,PATERNO,MATERNO,NOMBRE,SEGUNDO,LETRA
10,ARÉVALO,CORNEJO,NICOLÁS,ALEJANDRO,N
11,BARRIOS,MONTERO,BENJAMÍN,IGNACIO,B
12,BUSTAMANTE,LOYOLA,IGNACIO,HERNANDO,I
13,BUSTOS,GARRIDO,ARTURO,IGNACIO,A
```

this are the results on each line:

```
+ New-ADUser -SamAccountName $CUENTA -UserPrincipalName $CUENTA -Name $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo:NotSpecified: (CN=IGNACIO,UO=9...da.com:String) 
     [New-ADUser], ADException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8335,
Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

the head:
X,PATERNO,MATERNO,NOMBRE,SEGUNDO,LETRA

echo:
@{X=42; PATERNO=PAYACÁN; MATERNO=ZAPATA; NOMBRE=NICOLÁS; SEGUNDO=N; LETRA=}.NOMBRE

I know that reads the file and instead of reading just the column reads all the line($_), and then prints whatever I wrote next to it(".name", ".section", etc).

Comment: where is the header line for your CSV file?

Comment: Also, the $domain variable can’t be used in the OU path and the UPN. They are in different formats. UPN would be something@domain.com. The OU would be OU=something,dc=domain,dc=com unless you are somehow using the canonical name. Even then, it would be at the beginning of the OU path

Comment: Another potential problem: `$_.X -ge 10 -and $_.X -le 26` will likely not work as intended, because `Import-Csv` imports all values as _strings_, resulting in _lexical_ comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some variable and format changes to make this code more successful.

```
$domain=Get-ADDomain
Import-Csv -Path "C:\Alumnos.csv" |
  Foreach-Object {
    [int]$number= $_.X
    If($number -ge 10 -and $number -le 26)
    {
        $UO="991-5D"
    }

    $ou = "OU={0},{1}" -f $UO,$domain.DistinguishedName
    $UPN = "{0}{1}{2}@{3}" -f $_.LETRA,$_.PATERNO,$_.X,$domain.DNSRoot
    $CUENTA= "{0}{1}{2}" -f $_.LETRA,$_.PATERNO,$_.X

    New-ADUser -SamAccountName $CUENTA -UserPrincipalName $UPN -Name $_.NOMBRE `
    -SurName $_.PATERNO -GivenName $_.NOMBRE -EmailAddress $UPN `
    -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString "Leica666" -AsPlainText -force) -Path $ou `
    -Enabled $true -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Verbose
  }
```

**Explanation:**

- `$domain`: I've made this an ADDomain object. This allows the DistinguishedName and DNSRoot properties to be accessed where appropriate.
- `-f` operator: I used the format operator to make it easier to read the string concatenation attempts.
- `$ou`: This is constructed using the DistinguishedName of the domain. This is the proper format for the OU path.
- `$UPN`: This is constructed using the DNSRoot of the domain. It can obviously be different than your domain, but must be in an email address or FQDN format.

**Additional Comments:**

You are setting `-Name` to be `$_.NOMBRE`. This could be problematic because Name must be unique in each OU. Name is used to build the CN, which is where uniqueness is required. If you have NICOLAS in OU 991-5D, you are going to get an error if you try to create another NICOLAS in the same place. IMHO, I would do something different. You could also implement the use of splatting for building the properties of your `New-ADUser` command, but that is only for readability purposes. Below is an example of splatting:

```
$NewUserProperties = @{
    SamAccountName = $CUENTA
    UserPrincipalName = $UPN
    Name = $_.NOMBRE
    Surname = $_.PATERNO
    GivenName = $_.NOMBRE
    EmailAddress = $UPN
    AccountPassword = (ConvertTo-SecureString "Leica666" -AsPlainText -force)
    Path = $ou
    Enabled = $true
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $true
}

New-ADUser @NewUserProperties -Verbose
```

Comment: ha! good post ... i will delete mine now. the OP apparently can't be bothered to let me know that my "answer" has been read ... and your post makes it unneeded now. _thanks for doing the work_! [*grin*]

Comment: Sorry the error was in "UO=..." instead the correct sintaxis is "OU=..."
-- shame -- shame -- shame--
Thank you for your answer! you too, Lee_Dailey